# How to see the SQL expression of an X++ select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have below statement in a job in AX:

```
select RecId from pjiTable 
    join pID, Type, PrId from sjTable
    where pjiTable.Prid == sjTable.PrId &&
         (sjTable.Type == PjType::TimeMaterial || sjTable.Type == PjType::FixedPrice);
```

I have to use it in SQL Server. How can I convert this `select` statement into SQL and use it in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 9):

For debugging purposes you can change your `select` query and use [getSQLStatement](https://dynamicsaxgyan.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/get-underlying-sql-query-using-getsqlstatement-dynamics-ax-2012/) method on your table:

```
select generateOnly forceLiterals RecId from pjiTable 
    join pID, Type, PrId from sjTable 
    where pjiTable.Prid == sjTable.PrId  &&
         (sjTable.Type == PjType::TimeMaterial || sjTable.Type == PjType::FixedPrice);    
info(pjiTable.getSQLStatement());
```

This will show you SQL statement without actually executing the statement.

Comment: You can also add `forceLiterals` to see exact values instead of parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx